# ES6/7 Objects Assign Deep

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to do this with 2 objects in Javascript

```
const a = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 1,
    d: 2
  }
};

const b = {
  b: {
    c: 3
  }
};

Object.assign({}, a, b)
```

and want to see such result

```
a: 1,
b: {
  c: 3,
  d: 2
}
```

but I got this

```
 a: 1,
 b: {
   c: 3
 }
```

Where is the mistake ? Is it posible to do or not ?
How to "merge" 2 objects with deep structure

Comment: You'd need to use a recursive merging utility; all assign does is assign, which will overwrite key values.

Comment: [MDN has a warning for deep cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone). You'll need to use another method.